# TimeZone issues on windows Ce 6.0

Tags: windows, time-zone, windows-ce

We are using a windows CE 6.0 at work for our units and before we ship them we change the time zone, but somehow the time zone setting is getting changed to the default one after a while.

My co-worker suggested we change the default setting for the time zone in the registry. And of course they assigned the project to me (the guy who knows nothing about operating systems).

Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You might look at this document:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488025%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx

for example set:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Time Zones]
"@": REG_SZ
@="Eastern Standard Time"
```

where:

```
"Eastern Standard Time"
```

is the name that should match entry in the registry tree:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Time Zones\Eastern Standard Time]
```

Its strange that your device changes time zone on its own, I have seen devices that was setting time from GPS - maybe your device is settings time and also changing timezone?